# Debug can't find landing page

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm not sure what is going on with my project or VS setup.

- Two days ago I had a simple ASP NET Core app that was working (running in debug mode) and I could break point JavaScript inside VS.
- Yesterday I installed some SyncFusion components (Essential JS 2) on my dev system, but have not used or added any to my project at this point.
- Today when I try to debug (with IIS Express) I get directed to a browser page.

**file:///C:/%5CProgramData%5CMicrosoft%5CVisualStudio%5CEdgeAdapter%5C########/landingPage.html**

######## masking actual folder

[image]

and VS raises an error dialog

[image]

The attempted landing page does exist at

```
"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\EdgeAdapter\########\landingPage.html"
```

The project properties Debug settings seem to be correct

[image]

Q: What other areas in VS 2019 should I be looking for correction or settings change ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by disabling JS debugging. I think its a VS problem.

Find this in the Run Options:
[image: Run Options]

Answer (score 1):

KEKN TV's answer is correct and should be marked as such. This error appears when you have 'Script Debugging' enabled with the Microsoft Edge browser.

You can disable Script Debugging, as he suggests;

OR

**Select a different Web Browser**.
I am able to run with Script Debugging enabled with Chrome and Firefox (using VS2022 and VS2017). As the error message states, the problem lies with the missing VisualStudio/**EdgeAdaptor**/../landingPage.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same on a project that worked fine yesterday, all I did was add the Core tools so I could do Migrations, those work fine but now I'm getting the same when trying to debug the solution.

what I did notice is while that error box is open I could put the Correct url into a browser session and the app worked fine, only no debugging. Naturally when I clicked the OK button VS shut down the session

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).